# NGINX Rate Limiting with high rates is not working without burst

Tags: nginx, rate-limiting, ngx-http-limit-req-module

I'm trying to set up nginx rate limiting with limit_req_zone and limit_req directives.

```
map $http_my_header $sample_key {
    default  "";
    "hello"  1;
}

limit_req_zone $sample_key zone=one:100m rate=30000000r/s;

server {
    listen          8020;
    server_name     localhost;

    limit_req_status 509;

    location / {
        limit_req_log_level notice;
        limit_req    zone=one;
        root   html;
    }
}
```

With this configuration I expecting Nginx to be able to process lots of request per second. But after a some rate (about 1000rps) some requests are rejected.
**Burst** with **nodelay** is actually helps and all working as expected.
Problem is I do not understand why. According [this](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/) article nginx rate limiting is based on time slots per millisecond. There are 30000 requests per time slot in my case. And it obviously cannot be overwhelmed.

So basically: **rate 30000000r/s and no burst** — ~1000rps, other are blocked. **rate 3000r/s and burst=10 nodelay** — ~3000rps. Why does nginx behave in that way?